# Why the slider is not displayed on the map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, slider

Earlier today thanks to Faiz Sandhi I managed to get a working Leaflet map. I have been tinkering it for the past day but I have become stuck once again. I tried to add a slider to my map from this [page](https://github.com/svitkin/leaflet-timeline-slider/) because it seemed to be the easiest one to do. What I did was download the .js file they have on the site and I added the code for my slider to my already existing working code of the map, but the slider is not appearing. What did I do wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <title>Leaflet, Demo Fazal!</title>
    <style>#mapid { height: 380px; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
 integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
 crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="leaflet-timeline-slider.min.js"></script>




    <script>
    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([22.306841, 73.119037], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([22.306841, 73.119037]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();


L.control.timelineSlider({
                timelineItems: ["Day 1", "The Next Day", "Amazing Event", "1776", "12/22/63", "1984"],
                extraChangeMapParams: {greeting: "Hello World!"}, 
                changeMap: changeMapFunction })
            .addTo(mymap);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included neither a `changeMapFunction`, but only have passed a reference of it to `changeMap` nor have defined `data`. These are the two things you are missing.
Here is a working example of how it should be:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <title>Leaflet, Demo Fazal!</title>
  <style>
    #mapid {
      height: 380px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapid"></div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://svitkin.github.io/leaflet-timeline-slider/src/leaflet-timeline-slider.js"></script>




  <script>
    data = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [{
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "title": "Day 1",
            "content": "This is where some people moved to."
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-73.7949,
              40.7282,
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "title": "The Next Day",
            "content": "This is where some people grooved to."
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-74.3838,
              40.9148,
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "title": "Amazing Event",
            "content": "This is where they went to have fun."
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              4.899431,
              52.379189,
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "title": "1776",
            "content": "This where they went when the revolution had begun."
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-71.3489484,
              42.4603719,
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "title": "1776",
            "content": "This where they went when the revolution had begun."

          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-71.2272,
              42.4473,
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "title": "1984",
            "content": "So they all came here...and disappeared without a trace!"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-0.118092,
              51.509865,
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "title": "12/22/63",
            "content": "Now, this can be quite the scary place."
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-70.2553259,
              43.661471,
              1
            ]
          }
        },
      ]
    }
    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([22.306841, 73.119037], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.marker([22.306841, 73.119037]).addTo(map)
      .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
      .openPopup();


    changeMapFunction = function({
      label,
      value,
      map,
      exclamation
    }) {
      map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
          map.removeLayer(layer);
        }
      });

      filteredData = data.features.filter(function(i, n) {
        return i.properties.title === label;
      });

      var markerArray = [];
      L.geoJson(filteredData, {
        onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
          content = `${exclamation} <br> ${feature.properties.content} <br> (${Math.round(value/6 * 100)}% done with story)`
          var popup = L.popup().setContent(content);
          layer.bindPopup(popup);
          markerArray.push(layer);
        }
      }).addTo(map);

      var markerGroup = L.featureGroup(markerArray);
      map.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds()).setZoom(12);
    };



    L.control.timelineSlider({
        timelineItems: ["Day 1", "The Next Day", "Amazing Event", "1776", "12/22/63", "1984"],
        extraChangeMapParams: {
          greeting: "Hello World!"
        },
        changeMap: changeMapFunction,
        extraChangeMapParams: {
          exclamation: "Hello World!"
        }
      })
      .addTo(map);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh I didn't knew that, this was not written in the instructions and I am just doing something like this for the first week. Thank you for helping out! I will use this to reference in the future what I should do when I try to add something to my code from internet!